# has_many through same table Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I want to create a Rails app that allows "users" to follow other users. I am semi-new to more complex relationships and am attempting to set up has_many through for the first time. I want friends to be able to follow other users.

Here is my join table:

```
class Following < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"

end
```

Here is my users table:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_many :followings
has_many :followers, through: :followings

end
```

Here is my schema:

```
create_table "followings", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "follower_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

I don't know how to set up a form to actually create the relationship. In a users view, I have this, but it doesn't work.

```
<%= form_for @following do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :follower_id, :value => @user %>
<%= f.select :user_id, @users.collect { |u| [u.name, u.id] } %>
<%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

As I said, I am very new to this type of relationship. I need help. I don't know how to link records through a form.

I am following this tutorial: https://teamtreehouse.com/library/what-is-a-hasmany-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a `current_user` method that returns the logged in user - like what Devise provides. If not you need to setup authentication first.

Create a nested route:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :followings, only: [:create, :destroy], shallow: true
end
```

Add a validation to Following  to avoid duplicates:

```
class Following < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: 'follower_id'
end
```

Add a utility method to User to see if he is following another user:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followers, through: :followings

  def following?(user)
    followings.exist?(user: user)
  end

  def find_following(user)
    followings.find_by(user: user)
  end
end
```

We can then add Follow and Unfollow buttons (they are actually forms) to the `/users/show.html.erb` view.

```
<% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
  <%= button_to "Unfollow", current_user.find_following(@user), method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Follow", [@user, @user.followings.new] %>
<% end %>
```

Note that we don't need any form params since we are using a nested route (`POST /users/:user_id/followings`) to pass the user id (who gets followed) and we are getting the current user from the session.

We can then setup our controller:

```
class FollowingsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /users/:user_id/followings
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @following = Following.new(user: @user, follower: current_user)
    if  @following.save
      redirect_to @user, success: "You are now following #{ @user.name }"
    else
      redirect_to @user, error: "Could not create following"
    end
  end

  # DELETE /followings/:id
  def destroy
    @following = Following.find(params[:id])
    @following.destroy
    redirect_to @following.user, success: "You are no longer following #{ @user.name }"
  end
end
```